# When I use importmulti with an xprv it never imports the private keys. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

When I call:

```
bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "pkh(tprv8iDvhA6eaMDbRuH3D2DTNuH6N6LvMTVrcv7z6sVxyyYvThSaCSa3i3qFVqUgVL4NbVkACxjx3KPWLoP5jvDU3i16hjTnzEFnZuqsnTJ5F4n/*)"
```

it returns:

```
{
  "descriptor": "pkh(tpubDEuxqa8tiiuGKNJq6ft3nJwCw7rrWngmCDimPPYGQFMKJBhLpqPdtYT7fzuDbk1AppxRdYjzeUrLaVNQRP7EYghzLDBMguY2LHHHeHMtzhm/*)#0wkkha79",
  "isrange": true,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": true
}
```

I then call:

```
bitcoin-cli importmulti '[{ "desc": "pkh(tpubDEuxqa8tiiuGKNJq6ft3nJwCw7rrWngmCDimPPYGQFMKJBhLpqPdtYT7fzuDbk1AppxRdYjzeUrLaVNQRP7EYghzLDBMguY2LHHHeHMtzhm/*)#0wkkha79", "timestamp": "now", "range": 100, "watchonly": false, "label": "Hot Storage", "keypool": false, "rescan": false }]'
```

It returns:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "warnings": [
      "Some private keys are missing, outputs will be considered watchonly. If this is intentional, specify the watchonly flag."
    ]
  }
```

I am importing an xprv because I want to import the private keys, but they always get imported as watch-only.

Why is this? Is it intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong. This behavior is expected for Bitcoin Core 0.18. The [Pull Request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/15024) allowing private keys to be derived from descriptors and imported with `importmulti` was merged recently. This functionality will be included in Bitcoin Core 0.19.

Comment: I am testing this with 0.19.0 rc3 but its still behaving the same way, forcing the wallet to be cold. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you import the descriptor with the tprv of the tpub? `getdescriptorinfo` returns the descriptor with only pubkeys. To get the checksum for the private key descriptor, check the `checksum` field and add it to your descriptor.